# При создании проекта MVC 4 возникает ошибка, как ее устранить

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

При создании проекта MVC 4 возникает ошибка, как ее устранить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: интересно, а что показывается по кнопке "справка"

Comment: какая именно у вас версия Visual Studio? в 2013-й был баг, который приводил к появлению этого диалога при правильно установленном .net

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что Вам необходимо зайти в операционной системе по пути:

> Панель управления -> Программы и компоненты -> Включение или
>   отключение компонентов Windows

Найти там пункты связанные с .NET Framework и установить недостающие компоненты. Там где-то должен быть пункт ASP.NET - нужно отметить его галочкой.

Также советую ознакомиться со статьей [Настройка платформы .NET Framework для веб-узлов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb398791(v=vs.100).aspx). Думаю у Вас что-то не доставлено в системе из .NET Framework.

Как говорит @PashaPash - возможно это ошибка VS. Необходимо попробовать обновить среду разработки и попробовать переустановить пакет NuGet. Также, есть статья, по фиксу данного бага: [Dialog box may be displayed to users when opening projects in Microsoft Visual Studio after installation of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/).

Comment: Все установил, но не работает.

Comment: @SVD102, а все установлено из компонент IIS? Может их не хватает... Как-то очень давно было что-то похожее, проблему решил установкой недостающих компонент.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду это http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level3/3_1.php
Но у меня нет в списке 4.5 версии

Comment: Добавил скрин, посмотрите.

Comment: Ну вот как я и говорил, у Вас не доставлены компоненты. У меня там есть ASP.NET 3.5 и ASP.NET 4.6. Может Вам в систему необходимо доставить .NET Framework?

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @SVD102, думаю это поможет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 4.5 же установлен у меня на ПК. Скрин выложил еще один.

Comment: @SVD102, посмотрите у меня в ответе, обновил. Добавил картинок. У меня все работает.

Comment: @DenisBubnov те настройки, которые вы привели в ответе - для полноценного IIS. У топикастера падает при попытке создать сайт с использованием IIS Express.

Comment: @PashaPash, но он пытается создать проект MVC 4, при этом у него установлен только ASP.NET MVC 3.  Мне удалить свой ответ?

Comment: @DenisBubnov ASP.NET MVC 4 подключается на уровне проекта, через nuget - ему не нужна глобальная установка. Скорее всего у топикастера VS 2013, и он напоролся вот на этот баг - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6/. Хотя, судя по комментам, такой же баг был и в 2015-й

Comment: @PashaPash, получается ему просто необходимо обновить среду разработки и переустановить пакет в NuGet

Comment: @PashaPash Студия у меня стоит 2012. Установил по новой Framework 4.6.2 но в окне компонентов windows данная версия не появилась.

Comment: @svd102 по ссылке из моего коммента выше есть патч для студии, который чинит эту ошибку. Просто поставьте его.

Comment: @PashaPash♦ Cпаисбо, но теперь следующая ошибка появилась: Не удается запустить веб сервер IIS Express.

Comment: @SVD102 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/finbar_ryan/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012/